# How to register an nsIModule DLL on Windows

Tags: windows, delphi, firefox, mozilla, xpcom

I've created a Windows library with an implementation of nsIModule (and nsIProtocolHandler) a while ago. I've only recently got round to debugging it some more, but FireFox doesn't run my library any more. I've tried to register my module again, with `regxpcom` and deleting `xpti.dat` and `compreg.dat`, but my contract-id doesn't get listed. If I try debugging firefox or regxpcom, it appears like my DLL doesn't get loaded (where they used to call `NSGetModule` of my DLL).

Has something changed to the registration process? Do I need to provide a `.xpt` file? It wasn't required before, and I don't need/use any interfaces of my own, so if I do it would be an empty type library anyway...

http://xxm.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/xxm/trunk/Delphi/gecko/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done a bit more searching, and found out what I need is to create an XPI file.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Creating_XPI_Installer_Modules